# Creating Selenium node

Tags: appium, selenium-grid

I am getting this error while i am trying to attach my real Android device as a Selenium node to hub?

**Couldn't register this node: The hub is down or not responding: Connect to x.x.x.x:4445 [/x.x.x.x] failed: Network is unreachable**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**config.json file :**

```
{ "capabilities": 
[ { 
"browserName": "Android",
 "version":"4.4.2", 
 "maxInstances": 3, 
 "platform":"ANDROID",
 "deviceName":"emulator-5554" } ],
 "configuration":
 { "nodeTimeout":120,
 "port":4728,
 "hubPort":4444, 
 "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy", 
 "url":"127.0.0.1:4728/wd/hub",
 "hub": "127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register",
 "hubHost":"127.0.0.1",
 "nodePolling":2000,
 "registerCycle":10000,
 "register":true, 
 "cleanUpCycle":2000,
 "timeout":30000, "maxSession":1 } 
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your `config.json` file that we provide to appium?

Comment: {
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName": "Android",
"version":"4.4.2",
"maxInstances": 3,
"platform":"ANDROID",
"deviceName":"emulator-5554"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"nodeTimeout":120,
"port":4728,
"hubPort":4444,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"url":"http://127.0.0.1:4728/wd/hub",
"hub": "127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register",
"hubHost":"127.0.0.1",
"nodePolling":2000,
"registerCycle":10000,
"register":true,
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":30000,
"maxSession":1
}
}

Comment: Avoid giving comments in code, instead edit your question with the code.

Comment: Also, I can see you are specifying `emulator-5554` as target device which is an emulator when you actually want to connect a real device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving config.json file which is working fine for me on selenium grid for android device as well as emulators. Give it a try.

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"browserName": "",
"version":"",
"maxInstances": 1,
"platform":"ANDROID"
}
],
"configuration":
{
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":30000,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"url":"http://127.0.0.1:4720/wd/hub",
"host":"192.168.1.163",
"port": 4723,
"maxSession": 1,
"register": true,
"registerCycle": 5000,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "192.168.1.163"
}
}
```

I am getting below error message.

**error**: `

> uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined date=Fri
>   Oct 30 2015 10:31:30 GMT+0530 (IST), pid=2850, uid=1020000013,
>   gid=1020000013,
>   cwd=/home/sandeepreddy/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium,
>   execPath=/usr/bin/nodejs, version=v0.10.37, argv=[node,
>   /usr/bin/appium, --nodeconfi**

`

Comment: This command will be enough na to set as a node. appium --nodeconfig /path/to/nodeconfig.json.

Comment: i am getting  uncaughtException: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined error now.

Comment: Is the problem not solved? Can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: Well, I did not face this issue earlier. :( Is the Port No. you are providing in url is the one on which appium running?

Comment: Yes exactly same appium running on that port number only..Should i give ../wd/hub in url or not ?

Comment: Thanks dude..Now working fine...I restarted appium, my machine ..so on..now working fine..Strange behavior..But finally working...

Comment: Now i succeessfully attached 1 real device..Now i want to add more..where should i change that port number..?

Comment: You need to add another set of capabilities and configuration in same config.json file. Remember, One appium = one device connected to grid. Though I did not tried connecting multiple devices on grid. But this is the way. You can try it.

Comment: Yes i did like that..i taken other capabilities in another json file and run through that command with that file.but i am getting the below error.

Comment: error: Couldn't start Appium REST http interface listener. Requested port is already in use. Please make sure there's no other instance of Appium running already.

Comment: Of course you need to open appium with different port number from the one which you already connected one device. You can take help of appium website to make it work, instead of I comment more on this.